# Prevent Flipclock countdown timer to stop restarting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I prevent Flipclock countdown timer to stop restarting when ever someone refreshes the web page?

This the code I tried to use

```
<div class="clock"></div>
<div class="countdownHeader"><span>Sale Ends Midnit</span></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var clock;

     clock = jQuery('.clock').FlipClock({
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        autoStart: false,
        showSeconds: false,
        callbacks: {
          stop: function() {
             jQuery('.clock,.countdownHeader').hide();
          }
        }
     });

    /*clock.setTime(counter);*/
     clock.setTime(452540.668);
     clock.setCountdown(true);
     clock.start();

  });
</script>
```

Comment: don't hardcode this `clock.setTime(452540.668);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use cookie to solve this.

You can set the timer in cookie and when page refresh, you check if cookie is set, get that timer value else restart the timer.

Check this link to how to use cookie: [Working with Cookies](https://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function secsToMidnight() {
  var now = new Date();
  var then = new Date(now);
  then.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
  return parseInt((then - now) * 60 / 6e4);
}

var clock = $('.your-clock').FlipClock( secsToMidnight(),{
 countdown: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br>
<div class="your-clock"></div>
```

calculate secs left until mid night and set it to your clock.

Answer (score 0):

If you can supply the d2 string from the server (or hard code, I guess, if you must):

```
// Date to
var d2 = new Date('2017-09-01 00:00:00');
// Date now on client
var d1 = new Date($.now());
// Subtract one from the other
var seconds = (d2 - d1) / 1000;
// Dates and seconds to go
console.log('seconds: ' + seconds + ' => d2: ' + d2 + ' => d1: ' + d1);
```

then this will give you the parameter for clock.setTime(seconds);